# Client side can't fetch server response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api

## The Problem

I deployed a create-react-app webapp to aws ec2. It's used to display data from a database and send data to it. I use ExpressJS, CORS and MySQL.
With the following code i fetch the corresponding URL and the server.js sends back the database content. Until here, everything works fine.

```
getBets = _ => {
        fetch("http://ec2***.amazonaws.com
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => this.setState({bets: response.data}))
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    };
```

The problem begins when sending data to the database with the following code:

```
addBet = _ => {

        const { bet } = this.state;

        fetch(`http://ec2***.amazonaws.com/bets/add?name=${bet.person_name}&bet=${bet.time_bet}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(this.getBets)
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    };
```

On click the *addBet*-function populates the db, but in chrome I following error:

```
GET http://ec2***.amazonaws.com/bets/add?name=Peter%20Pan5&bet=10:17%205 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

and

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Regarding chrome dev-tools, the first error corresponds to the fetch in the *addBet* function and the second error to the catch part.

On the server side I've the following code for processing the fetch:

```
app.get("/bets/add", (req, res) => {
    const {name, bet} = req.query;
    const INSERT_BET = `INSERT INTO bets (name, bet, timestamp) VALUES("${name}", "${bet}", CURTIME())`;
    connection.query(INSERT_BET, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            return res.send("succesfully added your bet");
        }
    })
});
```

I want to mention, that the *res* paramter in the app.get part is unused. That tells me my IDE.
After a lot of hours digging deeper in the topics of expressJS and the fetch api, I guess, that the app.get part doesn't send a response to the server. But the fetch need some response.

## My Question

How do I have to change the code in the app.get part to send a proper response back to the server?
AND
Am I right with my guess?

Comment: Any error in console? status code?

Comment: The two errors in my initial post are the only ones. On server side, I'm not familiar with console of ec2 instances. Or in other words, I can't get the corresponding logs to my problem.

Comment: I mean browser's console from where you are calling API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MYSQL when you do an insert query you get back err,results and fields in the callback function like this:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'}, function (error, 
results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results.insertId);
});
```

You have used the parameter res for result and then you have used res.send() which now corresponds to that res parameter in the callback function and not the res object.Rewrite it like this:

```
app.get("/bets/add", (req, res) => {
const {name, bet} = req.query;
const INSERT_BET = `INSERT INTO bets (name, bet, timestamp) VALUES(?,?,?)`;
connection.query(INSERT_BET,[name,bet,CURTIME()] ,(err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
    }
    else {
        return res.send("succesfully added your bet");
    }
})
});
```

I have also used prepared statement in place of normal sql queries. These are used to prevent sql injections. I hope it will work now.

Comment: After change, I get an json error:
```SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0```
__and__
```GET http://ec2***.amazonaws.com/bets/add?name=Peter%20Pan&bet=10:17%20Uhr 500 (Internal Server Error)
```
Can the changed code process json formatted data?

Comment: Ok, apparently that did the trick. the new error was because of the non-json format of the response. I changed it to proper json style. Now, I don't get any (new) errors. Thanks a lot. You're awesome!
BTW: This link was also helpful to me
[Unexpected Token < in JSON at Position 0](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1239019/Unexpected-Token-in-JSON-at-Position)

Comment: @marco You are sending a string response in case when the insert is successful and an error response(console.log the error and check its type) and then in the client side you have written response.json(). As the response is not in json maybe that is why it is showing that error. Remove .json from response and also use console.log() to see the type of err in the console

Comment: You are welcome. I also checked out this link for the json error